# Создание консольного приложения Visual C# в Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, консоль

Как создать Visual C# Console Application в Visual Studio 2015 Professional, если его нет в списке Templates?

Comment: в строку поиска введите 'Console' должен найти

Comment: @user3373603, попробовал - ничего не выводит. Когда я в Templates выбираю Visual C#, то всё что выводит это - WPF Application, Silverlight Application и Silverlight Class Library. Когда в подпункте Visual C# выбираю Windows, то мне предлагает скачать набор из разных шаблонов - если я это сделаю, то это может добавить мне также консольное приложение? Или есть ещё какие-нибудь способы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для консольного приложения шаблон не особенно нужен, попробуйте обойтись без него, а **для этого**:

1. Создаем пустой проект
2. В свойствах проекта в `Output type` выбираем `Console Application`
3. Добавляем в `References` проекта ссылку на `System.DLL`
4. Добавляем в проект класс
5. Создаем в классе метод `static void Main() { }`  или как в оригинальном шаблоне `static void Main(string[] args) { }`, если планируете использовать аргументы командной строки.

**Консольное приложение готово.**

Если лень все это делать каждый раз, сохраните проект как шаблон ([**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)) и пользуйтесь. Можете добавить в шаблон часто используемые сборки, заготовки классов и методов - в общем, все что считаете нужным. Бывает полезно сделать несколько заготовок заранее и не заниматься ручной копипастой.

Таким образом можно создать абсолютно любой проект, некоторые проще, некоторые сложнее, все зависит от уровня ваших знаний и желания.

А вообще, стандартные шаблоны ставятся вместе с компонентами студии, но иногда что-то идет не так. Можете попробовать выполнить восстановление в инсталляторе студии, или просто переустановить, но все это потребует довольно много времени, особенно переустановка, даже на очень хорошем железе, так что тут выбор за вами.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы консольное приложение появилось, всего лишь нужно переустановить программу и в установщике выбрать все для Windows. У меня так появилось